# Unable to make asynchronous call using Windows Phone Background Task

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Background Task for my Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app.

The background task runs fine, but when I put call asynchronous method in it, it simply freezes at this stage. Using the debugger, it just stops. I cannot step through the code or anything.

Below is my code:

```
public sealed class bgTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan minus28 = new TimeSpan(0, 28, 0);
            DateTime timeGone = timeNow.Subtract(minus28);

            int resultsCount = await GetCount();

            ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
            XmlNodeList textElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            textElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("New Pictures!"));
            textElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(resultsCount + " new images in your area"));
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml));

            _deferral.Complete();
        }

        private async Task<int> GetCount()
        {
            string page = "http://en.wikipedia.org/";

            // ... Use HttpClient.
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                // ... Read the string.
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // ... Display the result.
                if (result != null &&
                result.Length >= 50)
                {
                    //resultsCount = 1888;
                }
            }

            return 9999;
}
```

While debugging, it will go inside the GetCount() method, and then just stops on the await GetCount() section.

Been trying to solve this for days. Help is GREATLY appreciated. :)

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask they have nice examples of what you're trying to do.  The only difference I see other than your custom setup, is that they always have `BackgroundTaskDeferral` defined at the class scope level and not inside the Run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the deferral at class scope. This wasy the deferral will be requested on creation and start of the backgroundtask.

```
    public sealed class bgTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            //Handle async stuff
            _deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
```

More information about this can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Comment: @user3102785 if my answer resolved your problem. Please mark the question as answered.